# When redirecting from server, the page being redirected from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, https, sails.js, load-balancing

We have an application running on an Amazon Beanstalk service, that using sails.js as server, and Backbone.js as client.

We want the site to be secure, so we need to allow only https access as protocol.

The problem:
We have a load balancer that gets HTTPS protocol and direct the trafic to HTTP port 8080. This caused that when redirecting from node.js (sails), the page being redirected to unsecure protocol, beacause the app doesn't know it came from secure one...

Is there any workaround about this issue?

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next)
{
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
  else  
  {
      // here the protocol is replaced with http
      res.redirect('/login#');
  }
}
```

Comment: I don`t understand, the problem is that the code attached is redirecting to HTTP when it`s not supposed to?

Comment: Yes. It should redirect to https (The protocol in the page url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need to check the [X-Forwarded-Proto](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-proto) header to see if the user's connection to the load balancer is over HTTP or HTTPS. Then redirect to HTTPS if it is HTTP.

Regarding your code redirecting to HTTP, it looks like you aren't doing anything in your code to actually redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, you are just redirecting to a login page without changing the protocol.